# Replacing text only at end of string

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a few names such as: `page_1.something.signature`

I want to replace `.signature` with `.date` so I use something like:

```
var string = "page_1.something.signature"
string = string.replace('.signature', '.date');
```

But what if my string is `page_1.signature.signature`? Then my string ends up being `page_1.date.signature`.

So my question is, how do I only apply the replace function to the end of the string and ignore the **.something**?

Comment: Is it always at the end or do you want to replace the last one?
So `abc.def.def.ef` => option 1 (last def to xyz) => `abc.def.xyz.ef` or option 2: `abc.def.def.ef` because def isn't at the end.

Comment: It's always at the end. But I'd be interested in learning about other ways as well. Such as the first occurrence.

Comment: .replace with an regular expression only replaces the first occurrence. So when you want to replace the last one you can reverse the strings :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var string = "page_1.something.signature"
string = string.replace(/\.signature$/, '.date');
```

This approach uses a regular expression. The `$` at the end means the string must end with the pattern before it. If you've not used regular expressions before , they're worth reading a about and make things like this easy.

Comment: It uses a regular expression. The $ at the end means the string must end with the pattern before it. If you've not used regular expressions before they're worth reading a bit about, make stuff like this very easy.

Comment: Yes, *I know,* I'm working on the assumption that the OP doesn't (hence the initial approach): add that information *to your answer* where it's more likely to be read, and of use, than here in the comments.

Comment: wouldn't I need `.replace(/\.signature$/` to include the period?

Comment: @bryan: either that, or simply remove the period from the `'.date'` string.

Comment: Thank you @garryp. This worked great and thank you for explaining it in the commends (and thanks David for asking). If you can just fix the answer real quick with my above comment so as to not confuse anyone, i'd love to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd offer a more functional approach to achieve a similar result, this approach replaces the *last occurrence of* the string passed to the function (whether it's at the end of the string, or otherwise). That said, here's the function:

```
function replaceLastOccurrence(haystack, needle, replacement) {
  // if you don't supply the required arguments, or the string to
  // replace is not in the string we pass to the function) we do nothing
  // I chose to return haystack (if it exists) or false (if it does not):
  if (!haystack || !needle || !replacement || haystack.indexOf(needle) === -1) {
    return haystack || false;
  }


  // breaking original string into an array of single-characters:
  var newString = haystack.split('')

  // using Array.prototype.splice() to manipulate the array,
  // finding the sequence of characters beginning at the lastIndexOf()
  // the string you're looking to replace, removing the array-elements
  // equal to the length of the string you want to replace (needle.length)
  // and replacing those array elements with the replacement-string:
  newString.splice(haystack.lastIndexOf(needle), needle.length, replacement)

  // because splice manipulates the original array, but returns
  // the array-elements it removes, we here join the array back
  // together to form a String using Array.prototype.join(''):
  return newString.join('');
}

var string = 'page_1.something.signature.more.signature.keys',
    newString = replaceLastOccurrence(string, 'signature', 'date');
```

```js
function replaceLastOccurrence(haystack, needle, replacement) {
  if (!haystack || !needle || !replacement || haystack.indexOf(needle) === -1) {
    return haystack || false;
  }
  var newString = haystack.split('')

  newString.splice(haystack.lastIndexOf(needle), needle.length, replacement)

  return newString.join('');
}

var string = 'page_1.something.signature.more.signature.keys',
  newString = replaceLastOccurrence(string, 'signature', 'date');

console.log(newString); // 'page_1.something.signature.more.date.keys'
```

To demonstrate the output of several strings:

```js
function replaceLastOccurrence(haystack, needle, replacement) {
  if (!haystack || !needle || !replacement || haystack.indexOf(needle) === -1) {
    return haystack || false;
  }

  var newString = haystack.split('')

  newString.splice(haystack.lastIndexOf(needle), needle.length, replacement);
  return newString.join('');
}

var originals = document.querySelectorAll('.original');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(originals, function(original) {
  original.nextElementSibling.textContent = replaceLastOccurrence(original.textContent, 'signature', 'date');
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul {
  margin-top: 4em;
}
li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
.original::after {
  content: ': ';
}
.output {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="original">something</span><span class="output"></span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="original">page_1.something.signature</span><span class="output"></span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="original">page_1.something.signature.another</span><span class="output"></span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="original">page_1.something.signature.signature</span><span class="output"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling).
- [`String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Seems like a lot of code for something so simple. Could you explain what makes this a better option then a one line `.replace(/string$/, "replacement")` ?

Comment: I didn't say it was 'better,' I would, however, argue that it's more flexible (if the last occurrence of the word to replace is in the middle of the string, for example, where regular expressions are more difficult). And as for 'a lot of code'? Really? It does its job, and, if you use the function-approach, doesn't really add anything to the file-size. It is, though, an option; it's not compulsory. (Incidentally, strip out the code-comments and it's only marginally more verbose than the regular expression solution.)